# Creating an efficient (but complex) NHibernate query

Tags: database, nhibernate, criteria

Here is roughly our data model (the entity names are fake and only for example purposes).

**Product** has a many-to-many relationship with **Shipper**. **Shipper** then has a one-to-many relationship with **Warehouse**.

Basically: **Product** has many **Shippers** which have many **Warehouses**.

We have a mapping from **Product** to **Shipper** and from **Warehouse** to **Shipper**. But NOT FROM **Shipper** to **Product** or **Warehouse**.

I've been trying to construct a query to return (for now just the count of) all the **Warehouses** which are related to a particular **Product**.

First Attempt: Got a list of **Shippers** from the **Product**. Created a query for **Warehouse** where the **Shipper** was IN our set. This works, but it's two queries. We need it to be one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you do need a mapping from **Shipper** to **Product** to make this work. But that's okay, just make it a no-access "query only" property.

Then it's as simple as doing a sub-select:

```
var subcriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Shipper>()
                .CreateCriteria("Products", "productsForCategory")
                .Add(Property.ForName("productsForCategory.Id").Eq(product.Id))
                .SetProjection(Projections.Id());
```

And then putting that **IN** the other query:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Warehouse>()
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Shipper", subcriteria))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
from warehouse w 
where w.Shipper in 
     (select p.shippers from product p where p.id = 2)
```

Comment: Essentially yes. But how can this be constructed using the Criteria API?

Comment: Can't help you there, I've always stuck the HQL format because I found it more powerful and easier to predict what SQL would end up getting to the database.